# .Net MVC Server to Server communications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, websocket, signalr

I need to do some simple comms between two sites, including the case where the same website acts as both the client and server.
The client needs to call a server function with signature something like:

```
complexObject GetData( int, string)
```

I'm on c#, .Net MVC 4.5 and running on Windows 7 for dev and & Server 2008 for hosting.  I'm looking at both Websockets and SignalR, but can't decide on suitability (I don't need javsacript support, it's purely client/server).  There also seems to be limitations running Websockets below Windows server 2012, and on combining client & server in the same app/website ( I could remove that requirement if its a serious issue).
Any advice on the right way to go would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use WebSocket in ASP.NET unless you are using Internet Information Server 8, so you would need Windows 8 or Windows 2012 server.

SignalR will fallback to SSE, ForeverFrame or LongPolling if you are not using IIS8. SSE is unidirectional from server to client, and does not work in IE.

You can host a WebSocket component in a worker role, that runs in the same domain but in different port. Running in the same domain, the WS connection will send the cookie during the HTTP negotiation, but you would have to work out how to associate the user identity.

You can use for example:

- XSocket.NET: http://xsockets.net/
- SuperSocket: http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/

That said, you can still use other technologies for communicating from server to server, like a duplex WCF channel.

- [A Beginner's Guide to Duplex WCF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/491844/A-Beginners-Guide-to-Duplex-WCF)
- [Duplex Service in WCF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/660479/Duplex-Service-in-WCF)

Cheers.

Comment: So SingnalR is left out of the original 2. I'll check out the others, is there a current preference for simple client server, including the other options?  Is signalR considered overkill?  I tried a quick test last night and got a client to server call working and returning the data I need.  Handling errors may be an issue as it blasts up an ugly response message on the client, so I'll need to check I have full control there.

Comment: If your client is a browser, go with SignalR if it is not complicated, or go directly to WebSockets. If the client is not a browser, I will go with WCF.